# Split whitespaces and search user input

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have an input field where users can search a database for a certain name. The database contains names such as "Doe, John".

If a user searches for "john" I think it's easy to implement. However, if he or she searches for "john Doe" I would like to implement the logic search for john or search for doe.

With RegEx I am completely lost. Is something like this even possible? However, with JS I would at least be able to consider this algorithm:

- Split the input on a whitespace and create to arrays
- Remove special characters
- Filter the JSON object retrieved from the database
- check, whether item includes the cleansed string-arrays

As for the JS-functions I tried something (in vain):

```
        let search = 'John Doe' //user input
        let data = ['Doe, John', 'Bean, Mister'] //data from database
        let split = search.split(" ") //split the whitespace into two arrays
        split = split.map(item => { return item.replace(/[^\w\s]+/gi, '')}) //remove dots, commas etc.
        let result = data.filter(item => { //filter each item from the data... 
            split.forEach(element => {
            let found = item.match(new RegExp(element, "i")) // so here I get matches, but how can I move them up the let the filter method return true?
            return found.length
            }).length>0


        })
        console.log(result)
```

Thanks to Taplars comment, I have used a map-method instead of a forEach:

```
let data = ['Doe, John', 'Bean, Mister']
    let split = search.split(" ")
    split = split.map(item => { return item.replace(/[^\w\s]+/gi, '')})
    let result = data.filter(item => {
      let filtered =   split.map(element => { 
            let ret = item.match(new RegExp(element, "i"))
            return ret
        })
      console.log(item,filtered) //now I have two arrays, one with something meaningful and one with [null,null]. How can I remove empty arrays?
      return filtered.length>0 
    })
    console.log(result)
```

Comment: `forEach()` do not return a value.  Thus your filter would never return results.

Comment: So you're saying you have the entire database now on the user machine (`let data = [*****]`) and you want to perform a multistring query? ... or is that Node js? What database do you use?

Comment: No, I have an axios.get request to pull certain data (around 100 records with names) to the client. Then I would like to find the matches... It's a membership programm made with vuejs.

Comment: Aha, I get it, because otherwise I was thinking of [Full Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

- Get the search expression and turn it into a series of regular expressions
- Iterate through the data and check to see if some or all the expressions match

```js
const data = ['Doe, John', 'Doe, Jane', 'Smith, John', 'Bean, Mister'] // data from database

function searchEvery(input) {
  const wordExpressions = input.split(/[^\w]+/g)
    .filter(word => word) // remove empty entries
    .map(word => new RegExp(word, 'i')); // convert to regular expression
  return data.filter(item => wordExpressions.every(exp => exp.test(item)));
}

function searchSome(input) {
  const wordExpressions = input.split(/[^\w]+/g)
    .filter(word => word) // remove empty entries
    .map(word => new RegExp(word, 'i')); // convert to regular expression
  return data.filter(item => wordExpressions.some(exp => exp.test(item)));
}

console.log(searchEvery('John Doe'))
console.log(searchEvery('John'))
console.log(searchEvery('Doe'))

console.log(searchSome('John Doe'))
```

Comment: Thank you, when looking at the result, I can see what's going on. Also thank you for pointing me into the methods, that I should try to understand better (.some, .every)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it non-greedy (every user **word is optional**)

```js
const data = ['Doe, John', 'Bean, Mister', 'Mardoe, Ann']; // data 
const search = '  joh  doe  '; // user input

// Remove spaces and create Piped | options
const searchPipe = search.trim().replace(/[|\s]+/g, '|');
const result = data.filter(item => new RegExp(searchPipe, 'i').test(item));

console.log(result)
```

To make it greedy (**must contain every word**)

```js
const data = ['Doe, John', 'Bean, Mister', 'Mardoe, Ann']; // data 
const search = '  joh  doe  '; // user input

// Remove extra spaces and create array
const searchArr = search.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ');
const result = data.filter(item => searchArr.every(sa => new RegExp(sa, 'i').test(item)));

console.log(result)
```

Notice, if a person named `"Doe, Doe"` was in the list, the above would account it (since the length) for a `"john doe"` search, but I think it's fine.

Comment: Two lines... Thank you so much. But, what are Piped options? The regex [|\s] basically says: find all whitespaces and then replace them with pipes... So the searchPipe becomes John|Doe... But what does .test() in conjunction with pipes? I suppose I also need to read more about the RexExp object...

Comment: @rasenkantenstein [`.test()` returns a boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) Pipe in Regex are Options, exactly, just like `john|doe` meaning, either `john` or `doe`. The `new RegExp` is there to allow variable insertion (our constructed piped string), and to pass the case insensitive flag `'i'`.